# (ssconvert: 2156) dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Cannot spawn a message bus without a machine-id

Tags: cygwin, dconf

I am trying to use `ssconvert` to convert `.xlsx` files to `.csv` formats. However, every conversion will report a warning message like:

```
(ssconvert:2156): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: 
Cannot spawn a message bus without a machine-id: Unable to load 
/var/lib/dbus/machine-id or /etc/machine-id: Failed to open file 
'/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': No such file or directory
```

which is still OK since the conversion seems to work well, but I have tens of thousands of such `.xlsx` files, and the terminal would be flooded by these warnings. And I am not sure if these warnings would slow down the process a lot. I am wondering what the cause is and what this warning means. I am using **cygwin64** on Windows 8.1. Maybe this is somehow related? Thanks.

PS: Alternatively, is it possible to suppress the warnings?

Comment: It seems you need the dbus demon running. May be `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon.exe --session` could help

Comment: I just had this problem today with ssconvert on cygwin on WIndows 11. The XLSX file is generated though and the tool does exit with status 0 (success) so - did you ever find a way to get rid of that message? I know I could redirect stderr and grep out that specific message but hoping for a more idiomatic solution for this specific tool, other than running some daemon that I may or may not have and don't need otherwise.